# Physics Equivalent of IUPAC Gold Book

Tags: definition

I wanted to look up a few definitions and found them to vary from source to source so I wondered if there was a book such as IUPAC Gold Book in Chemistry which formally lists and defines almost all phenomenon and principles of physics like angular momentum, spin magnetic moment etc.

Comment: The CRC handbooks might be the closest match. But, physics overall is not in quite the same need for defined uniformity in nomenclature as chemistry (particularly organic chemistry).

Comment: @JonCuster ok thanks for the info